# Finding node in group by matching nodes of other group

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have XML docs like this:

```
<groups>
  <group id="A">
    <file id="kr3" href="..."/>
    <file id="6ft" href="..."/>
    ...
  </group>
  <group id="B">
    <file id="8dg" href="..."/>
    <file id="g32" href="..."/>
    ...
  </group>
</groups>
<structs>
  <struct id="abc1">
    <filepointer id="kr3"/>
    <filepointer id="8dg"/>
    ...
  </struct>
  <struct id="abc2">
    <filepointer id="6ft"/>
    <filepointer id="g32"/>
    ...
  </struct>
</struct>
```

In XSLT I want to find the targetFileUrl.

The `struct` defines a mapping between files of different `group` nodes. So I provide a `sourceUrl` and a `targetGroupId`. And I want to get out the matching  node that is mapped in `struct`.

So I need to go this way:

- sourcehUrl = `'http://...'`
- targetGroupId = `'B'`
- sourceFileId = `//file[@href=$sourcehUrl]/@id`
- structId = `//struct/filepointer[@id=$sourceFileId]/../@id`
- targetFileId = ???
- targetFileUrl = `//file[@id=$targetFileId]/@href`

How to find the correct file ID that matches one `filepointer` in the given struct?

Comment: The short answer is to use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key). For a longer answer, we would need to understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish here (seeing the expected output could help in this).

Comment: As told above, I need to find the targetFileUrl. One URL maps to another URL of another file. This mapping is defined in the struct node. I already tried key but maybe I did not understand it correctly. I did now find a solution with two for-each loops. But I think there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, there is a better way: use a key. Unfortunately, I cannot demonstrate, because I don't understand what you describe. There is no `targetFileUrl` in your input.